# Unknown type name cpp

Tags: c++, header, implementation

Hello i have a problem with my program, the file Node.hpp keeps showing the error  "Unknown type  name 'ToDo'. I really don't know why and i am becoming silly!!
Does anyone know a possible solution?
Thanks:)
ToDo has his own hpp and cpp files with the same logic as the Node files do.

```
Node.hpp
---------------------
#ifndef Node_hpp
#define Node_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include "ToDo.hpp"

class Node{
public:
    Node *next;
    ToDo *element;
    Node(ToDo *element, Node * next);

};


#endif /* Node_hpp */

 Node.cpp
---------------------
#include "Node.hpp"
#include "ToDo.hpp"


Node::Node(ToDo *element, Node * next):
next(next), element(element)
{}

ToDo.hpp
-------------------------
#ifndef ToDo_hpp
#define ToDo_hpp

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


enum class Importanza{
   BASSA,MEDIA,ALTA
 };


class  ToDo{

public:
    ToDo(string titolo = "Titolo", string descrizione = "Descrizione",                     Importanza importanza = Importanza::BASSA);
    ToDo(ToDo* e);

string titolo() const; // dichiara che il metodo non modifica l'oggetto!!
void titolo(const string& v);
string descrizione() const;
void descrizione(const string& v);
Importanza importanza() const;
void show(int) ;
ostream& operator <<(ostream& o); //non vuole TODO xkè è implicito


private:
string m_titolo;
string m_descrizione;
Importanza m_importanza;




 };


 #endif /* ToDo_hpp */
```

Comment: Does perhaps "ToDo.hpp" include "Node.hpp"?

Comment: Search for and read about *circular inclusion*.

Comment: nope, "ToDo.hpp" includes no headers or anything else

Comment: @Plates Then show the contents of "ToDo.hpp".

Comment: sorry...ToDo.hpp added

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a forward declaration in Node.hpp, like this:

```
class ToDo;
```

Comment: ... and remove the `#include "ToDo.hpp"` as well.